# How can I control the number of running processes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm doing a shell script and the unknown situation occurred. I must execute a certain number of processes, lets suppose 12. But I want to limit the executions by 't' each time. So if 't' is 3 I would have to execute 3 processes then 3, 3 and finally 3. But I would like to do it automatically, so I need to monitore those running processes and when one of them has finished I must execute one of the remaining processes.

After some research, I have found the following command:

```
launch backgroundprocess &
PROC_ID=$!
while kill -0 "$PROC_ID" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    echo "PROCESS IS RUNNING"
done
echo "PROCESS TERMINATED"
```

Proposed by cuonglm.

This can help to know if a process is running or not. I tried to create 12 processes and save them in 3 different variables, but it isn't working properly.

```
processors=3
counter=0

for A in {1..12}
do
    counter=$((counter+1))
    backgroundprocess &
    PID[$A]=$!

    while [ $counter -eq $processors ]
    do
        if kill -0 "$PID[1]" >/dev/null 2>&1;
        then
            counter=$(($counter-1))
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

Do any of you know how can I do this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the improvement of your script.

`ps -o pid= -p ${PID[$i]}` returns `PID` if process exists.

`num` stands for the number of job finished.

```
processors=3
counter=0
num=0

for A in {1..12}
do
    counter=$((counter+1))
    sleep 4 &
    if [ $num -eq 0 ]
    then
        PID[$A]=$!
    else
        PID[$num]=$!
    fi
    echo "$A starts"
    echo $counter

    while [ $counter -eq $processors ]
    do
        for i in `seq 1 $processors`
        do
            if [ ! `ps -o pid= -p ${PID[$i]}` ]
            then
                counter=$(($counter-1))
                echo "$i stopped"
                num=$i
                break
            fi
        done
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The **jobs** built-in command of the shell can be used to count the background processes.

An additional file is used to wait the termination of background processes.

Give it a try, the tested script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash --

tmp_file=/tmp/`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S$$"`
rm -f "${tmp_file}"
touch "${tmp_file}"
max_nb_processes=12
max_parallel_nb_processes=3
nb_processes=0
while [ $nb_processes -lt $max_nb_processes ]
do
  if [ `jobs -r | wc -l` -lt $max_parallel_nb_processes ]
  then
    (backgroundprocess ; printf "end" "" >> "${tmp_file}")&
    ((nb_processes ++))
  else
    read -t 10 line < "${tmp_file}"
  fi
done
wait
```

---

For reference, the first version.

The tested version below use some polling:

```
#!/bin/bash --

poll_time_second=10
max_nb_processes=12
max_parallel_nb_processes=3
nb_processes=0
while [ $nb_processes -lt $max_nb_processes ]
do
  if [ `jobs -r | wc -l` -lt $max_parallel_nb_processes ]
  then
    backgroundprocess &
    ((nb_processes ++))
  else
    sleep $poll_time_second
  fi
done
wait
```

As long as there is less than 3 background processes, a new process is started in background.

When there are 3 background processes, the script sleep 10 seconds, before checking again.

When 12 background processes had been started, the script **wait** that the last ones end before terminating.

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with `rm -f "${tmp_file}"`, the *brace* enclosure serves no purpose there. `rm -f "$tmp_file"` is equivalent. (the same applies to the `touch` below)

Comment: In particular if you consider that the script generates the filename which is a list of digits; I mean there is no special chars in the filename.

Thank you for the information. I will have a look in man pages as well.

Answer (score 2):

Batches are easy, if you don't really care about keeping the processors busy.

```
processors=3
counter=0

for A in {1..12}
do
    backgroundprocess &
    ((counter++))
    if ((counter == processors)); then
        wait   # Block until all background jobs have completed
        counter=0
    fi
done
```